# Where can I find the source to the function argp_parse?

Tags: linux

I need the GNU Linux Code of the function

```
    error_t argp_parse(const struct argp *__restrict __argp,int,char **__restrict,unsigned     __flags,int * __arg_index,void *__restrict input)
```

If someone know where to get or have it ,please send it to me.
Thanks very much !!

Comment: Why don't you look for the source yourself?

Comment: OK,Now,I'm reading the code of the Linux command ‘tar’，I saw this function ，I didn't find the code of this function.I want to know what this function do and how it implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Part of glibc, so easily found following the links at gnu.org:

From http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=argp/argp-parse.c;hb=e07bb02a4f9e7d98f79f428a661c5b982286869d:

```
/* Parse the options strings in ARGC & ARGV according to the argp in ARGP.
   FLAGS is one of the ARGP_ flags above.  If END_INDEX is non-NULL, the
   index in ARGV of the first unparsed option is returned in it.  If an
   unknown option is present, EINVAL is returned; if some parser routine
   returned a non-zero value, it is returned; otherwise 0 is returned.  */
error_t
__argp_parse (const struct argp *argp, int argc, char **argv, unsigned flags,
      int *end_index, void *input)
{
  error_t err;
  struct parser parser;
…
```

Comment: It is in Glibc (not in Glib which is part of Gtk).